# A simple Insertion Sort implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I've written a InsertionSort algorithm in Java and I want a review on these:

- Performance improvements.
- Code conventions.
- Algorithm design improvements.
- Cleaner approaches.

I would highly appreciate if you can review based on the points above, and I would prefer if you can add more points on top if it if you find necessary.

Here's the code:

```
package com.hassanalthaf.sortingalgorithms;

public class InsertionSort {
    private final int SECOND_NUMBER_INDEX = 1;

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        for (int iterations = this.SECOND_NUMBER_INDEX; iterations < numbers.length; iterations++) {
            int currentNumber = numbers[iterations];
            int newIndex = iterations;

            for (int comparisons = iterations; comparisons > 0; comparisons--) {
                if (currentNumber < numbers[comparisons - 1]) {
                    newIndex--;

                    numbers[comparisons] = numbers[comparisons - 1];
                }
            }

            numbers[newIndex] = currentNumber;
        }
        return numbers;
    }  
}
```

Here's my main class calling the `InsertionSort` sort method:

```
package com.hassanalthaf.sortingalgorithms;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 20, 51, 12, 43, 2, 20};

        InsertionSort insertionSort = new InsertionSort();

        numbers = insertionSort.sort(numbers);

        for (int iterations = 0; iterations < numbers.length; iterations++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[iterations]);
        }
    }

}
```

This produces an output:

```
1
2
12
20
20
43
51
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- this code is not commented
  strikingly, it does not even have [doc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)
- given at least two classes from the same coder that do essentially the same thing, there *should* be an 'interface' - look for [one you can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) use (if as a template), especially from the Java API
- `SECOND_NUMBER_INDEX` is close to meaningless
- as a "genuine" constant, `SECOND_NUMBER_INDEX` should be static
- `int[] sort(int[] numbers)` would then not use any instance (data) members and should be a class/static method instead of an instance one
- if `iterations` was called `ordered` or `sorted`, the condition of the outer loop read close to a loop invariant
- having found the first element no bigger than `currentNumber`, continuing to index `0` isn't called for - just place `currentNumber` and `break` the inner loop, no need for `newIndex`

Use a [foreach-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in `main()`.